# What happens when two ergospheres of oppositely spinning black holes of the same mass, axis of rotation, and angular momentum approach?

Tags: black-holes, kerr-metric

What happens when two ergospheres of oppositely spinning black holes of the same mass, axis of rotation, and angular momentum approach each other?
What would happen to the black holes in question?